# django how to add multi values to a many to many relationship

Tags: python, django

I have list of strings from POST request and I want to create blog object 
with many values of hashtags, with this method it only creates hashtag 
object with 1 value and then overrides it, what can i do?

```
def myForm(request):
tags = HashTags.objects.all()
if request.method == 'POST':
    g = request.POST
    print(g)

    if g.get('title') and g.get('desc') and request.FILES.get('file'):
        obj = Blog.objects.create(
                title = g.get('title'),
                text = g.get('desc'),
                photo1 = request.FILES.get('file'))
        if g.get('VIN'):
            obj.Vin = g.get('VIN')
        if g.getlist('tags'):
            for i in g.getlist('tags'):
                print(i)
                a = HashTags.objects.filter(tag=i)
                obj.hashtag.tag = g.getlist('tags')[0]

        return redirect('blog:main')




class HashTags(models.Model):
tag = models.CharField(max_length=150,unique=True) #unique=True

def __str__(self):
    return self.tag




class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    text = models.TextField()
    photo1 = models.ImageField()
    photo2 = models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True)
    videoURL = models.CharField(max_length = 5000)
    hashtag = models.ManyToManyField(HashTags)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True,blank=True)
    pinVideo =models.BooleanField(null=True,blank=True,default=False)
    pinPhoto =  models.BooleanField(null=True,blank=True,default=False)
```

actual: randomtag2
expected: randomtag1 ,randomtag2

Comment: Which tags you want to set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use add for many to many fields

```
if g.getlist('tags'):
  hashtags = list(HashTags.objects.filter(tag__in=g.getlist('tags')))
  obj.hashtag.add(*hashtags)
```

Comment: god it works thank you so much, I couldn't find this solution in m2m relationship of official docs :( oh btw there is 1 mistake instead of obj.hashtag.tag.add(*hashtags) it will be obj.hashtag.add(*hashtags) I had similar mistake